# Change application name shown in Win7 taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, taskbar

I want to change the application name that shows up in windows 7 taskbar context menu.

[image]

My applicaiton currently shows my application name. I want to change it to something like microsoft product does

[image]

My application uses Prism framework and the application name I want to show will be decided on type of module. So I want to set the application name dynamically.

Comment: Show me what do you have in your `Assembly.cs` please.

Comment: Your application or your jump task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are seeing `vshost32.exe` because you are running under the debugger.  That's just the name of the host process used by the debugger and you cannot change that.  Well, I suppose you could but it's not what you want to do. You want to change the name used by your executable.

When you run without debugging, as your users will, the application name displayed on the taskbar app popup is determined by the assembly name specified in the Application page of the project config. So, just change that to whatever you want and there's nothing more to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am ware of it, I want to set it dynamically. I have not explained in  my question edited the same.

Comment: Oh, that's a completely different question. Well, I guess I wasted my time making all those nice screenshots then.

Comment: Word doesn't change this dynamically. I actually think that I answered the question you asked. I think you asked the wrong question!!

Comment: http://puu.sh/sxnyQ/374f8b35b3.png details all the things i've changed but the shortcut remains the same in windows 10

Answer (score 1):

With managed apps you set that property via the Windows API Code Pack Library, you can use the `AppID` property that is part of the `Taskbar` object, which you can find in the `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.Taskbar` namespace. Using that property you can set and get the application ID of a given application.

You can also set it manually (if not using the pack). Just set the name setting with it's id:

```
void SetAppID(HWND hWnd, int iAppID)
{
    IPropertyStore *pps;
    HRESULT hr = SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(hWnd, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pps));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        PROPVARIANT pv;
        if (iAppID >= 0)
        {
            hr = InitPropVariantFromString(c_rgszAppID[iAppID], &pv);
        }
        else
        {
            PropVariantInit(&pv);
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pps->SetValue(PKEY_AppUserModel_ID, pv);
            PropVariantClear(&pv);
        }
        pps->Release();
    }
}
```

And then calling it like:

```
private static void SetWindowAppId(string appId)
{
    Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.ShellNativeMethods.SetWindowAppId
        (OwnerHandle, "the name you want to display here");
}
```

See [here](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/06/18/developing-for-the-windows-7-taskbar-application-id.aspx) for a full example.

Answer (score 0):

In your root Window xaml, change the Title property of the Window.